# How can I make my chrome extensions popup to remain open unless closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

Currently I have this : 
[image]

I'd like to add an close[x] button at the right bottom corner. The popup should close only if user clicks on it. Now, it is closing whenever a click is made on the page.

How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no way to keep chrome extension open. Checkout this :http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-persist-popups

Comment: Thanks @radia, for letting me know.But I'd love that feature.